# How to take care of a new lens?

Tags: lens, equipment-protection, cleaning

I'm planning on purchasing a new lens for my camera for macro photography, specifically this one:

[Tamron AF 90mm f/2.8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00021EE4U)

I've heard that it is a good idea to put a "UV filter" on front on the lens. Is that true?

Also, what is the right way to clean a lens?

Any other advice for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding whether to use a filter for protection, see http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17854/is-a-uv-filter-required-recommended-for-lens-protection. For tips on cleaning a lens, see http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21493/how-can-i-clean-a-camera-effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are specific cleaning solutions that can be used with microfiber cloths that are designed to clean lenses without damaging the glass or the coatings.

As far as bumps/scratches, the most common ways to protect your lens are:

- [UV/Protection Filters](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1393/is-a-uv-filter-better-for-lens-protection-than-a-protector-filter)
- Lens hoods